# Make custom field readonly based on user role

Tags: roles, sugarcrm

In my Tasks editviewdefs.php...this is working for me. The field is readonly and cannot be edited. 
Can someone please help me make the 'type' => 'readonly' only apply if the users role matches 'Loan Officer'?

```
    array (
      0 => '',
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'processor_signoff_c',
        'label' => 'LBL_PROCESSOR_SIGNOFF',
        'type' => 'readonly',
      ),
    ),
```

I am using 6.5.14 Community Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution could be as follows:

File => custom/modules/Tasks/views/view.edit.php

```
/**
 * @see SugarView::display()
 */
public function display()
{
    if($this->ev->isDuplicate){
            $this->bean->status = $this->bean->getDefaultStatus();
    } //if

    global $current_user;

    // check if current user is in specific role
            $isEnabledRole = in_array("ITOperation", ACLRole::getUserRoleNames($current_user->id));
            if($isEnabledRole)
                $this->ev->ss->assign('readOnly', 'readonly = "readonly"');
            else
                $this->ev->ss->assign('readOnly', '');

    parent::display();
}
```

File => custom/modules/Tasks/metadata/editviewdefs.php

```
    array (

      array (
        'name' => 'description',
    'customCode' => '<input type="text" title="" value="{$fields.description.value}" id="description" name="description" {$readOnly}>',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

For checkbox input type then:
File => custom/modules/Tasks/views/view.edit.php

```
            if($isEnabledRole) {
                $this->ev->ss->assign('readOnly', 'readonly = "readonly"');
                $this->ev->ss->assign('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $this->ev->ss->assign('readOnly', '');
                $this->ev->ss->assign('disabled', '');
            }
```

File => custom/modules/Tasks/metadata/editviewdefs.php

```
      array (
        'name' => 'processor_signoff_c',
        'label' => 'LBL_PROCESSOR_SIGNOFF',
        'customCode' => '<input type="hidden" name="processor_signoff_c" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="processor_signoff_c" name="processor_signoff_c" value="1" {if $fields.processor_signoff_c.value == "1"} checked {/if} {$disabled}>',
      ),
```

Bye,
Antonio.

Comment: I actually found that same example, but my only issue with that was I could not get the <input type="checkbox".../> syntax to work. My value was value="{$fields.processor_signoff_c.value}" and it would not insert the correct value nor save to the database properly on save. If you could help me get the syntax of the <input type="checkbox"...> to work properly...I can mark this as a good answer

Comment: I integrated the answer, test if now is fine. Bye.

Comment: so grateful for your contributions...I will test later today and report back...I see where you are going and it looks promising

Comment: that did the trick, turns out my "views" folder was named "view"...and that was causing some confusion as well. much appreciated!